# What is the correct way to suppress deprecation warnings when building with `catkin build` in ROS?

Tags: cmake, ros, catkin

During building my ROS project using `catkin build`, I often times see deprecation warnings popping up which I deem useless information. This deprecation warnings are coming from my code and also it's dependencies (eg:Googletest, `catkin_tools_prebuild`)

I would like to suppress these deprecation warnings. After doing some research, it seems like I have to set CMAKE_WARN_DEPRECATED to False. How do I set this variable in ROS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found to work best in suppressing the deprecation warnings of all packages, including yours and it's dependencies, is to set the `CMAKE_WARN_DEPRECATED` in catkin config before doing `catkin build`.

In the catkin environment:

```bash
catkin config --cmake-args -DCMAKE_WARN_DEPRECATED=OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but why can't you add it to your CMAKELists file? As in, add this flag to your CMakeLists.txt file:

```
set(CMAKE_WARN_DEPRECATED OFF)
```

catkin is built on top of CMake so it should accept cmake flags.

Comment: While this may work to suppress deprecation warnings in your package, it doesn't suppress the ones generated from your package's dependencies.